# Convert object output in console to string in R

Tags: r

Consider the following R program:

```
library(arules)
data("iris")
train <- sapply(iris,as.factor)
train <- data.frame(train, check.names=FALSE)
txns <- as(train,"transactions")
rules <- apriori(txns, parameter = list(confidence =0.5, support= 0.01,     minlen= 1, maxlen= 3))
rules
```

This returns string "set of 479 rules".
How do I get value 479 from this string? My idea was to split this string with strsplit and take the third value in the array.

The problem is that `rules.toString()` gives an error:

> Error: could not find function "rules.toString"

Hence `strsplit(toString(rules)," ")` does not work.

Note: I do not want to convert the rules object to data frame to save processing time.

Comment: rules.toString won't work, we are not in python ;-)

Comment: Looking into `str(rules)`, we can try `rules@rhs@data@Dim[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in help `rules-class {arules}` has function `lenght`(`?arules::length`)

So you need

```
length(rules)
```

Comment: I tried to get rules object methods via  `methods(class=typeof(rules))`, which returned only method `coerce`. From this I inferred there is no length method, but know I see this procedure was not for some reason right.